# Fullcalendar hide events only in month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar

My problem is hidding events in a specific view.
I need to hide events only in month view.
Because in month view i have set on day click to redirect to the specific day in day view. and have colored days which depends on the events.

So i need that for better looking month view, with colored days only. and when i click on a day go to that and then appear all events normally.

I tried with eventLimit but with 0 value show all events.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: _Let the guessing game begins_

Comment: im searching if is there any function in fullcalendar that helps but nothing till now..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use css in order to hide events in month view only.

Code:

```
.fc-month-view .fc-event-container{
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ecjvb8b7/

Comment: drive me crazy you are the best.... I was thinking just something in javascript. thats was simple and working PERFECT !!!!
Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 5):

i'm using this method to hide events of specified view because sometimes its hard to update css

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
  if(view.type == 'month') {
    $(element).css("display", "none");
  } else {
    // Do nothing
  }
}
```